# PIN POTHA (puñña potha) or Merit Book, costom still alive? How to keep it up?

Tags: personal-practice, merit

My person just came across [an answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/19948/11235) by Upasak Suminda Sirinath S. Dharmasena, mentioning:

> Also there is a concept of Pin Potha, which is a journal of all good deeds done.

And

> It is an age old custom of the Sri Lankan Buddhists to maintain a record of One's meritorious activities. This record is named PIN POTHA or Merit Book.

Since such is not only a perfect daily reflection means, fitting in the praised [Anussatis](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/index-subject_en.html#recollections): Recollection of one's own virtues (silanussati), 
Recollection of one's own generosity (caganussati),
Recollection of the own qualities equal the devas (devatanussati), but also as telling, reminding very sick and dying people on their good deeds as support, my person wonders whether this custom is still alive.

Is such, keeping records of ones merits done,  still practiced in Sri Lanka?

And, since it can be used perfect also for the practice of sharing merits and the practice of rejoicing in merits, my person wonders if there are ideas how to make the basic practices more virtual, vital, knowing that modern people are hardly to motivate toward the basic practices. They might possible needs such as a "reputation system", possible implemented in other daily used software or online services.

[Some "experiments" had been done to encourage the nearly death basic section, such as [Anumodana](https://www.reddit.com/r/Anumodana/) or mail-list, next to [a section in use](http://sangham.net/index.php/board,5.0.html), to get some ideas.]

*(Note that this is not given for use for trade, exchange, stacks or entertainment but for encouragement toward release and benefical undertakings toward such)*

Answer (score 2):

As a Sri Lankan, I've heard these in our grand parent times (within last 20-30 years back). With the current lifestyle, everyone has started looking for happiness in outer world, most of the people have forgotten these kind of customs / traditions. This doesn't imply that `Pin Potha` is no longer active in Sri Lanka, but I should say its very hard to find now a days.

As I've heard the main purpose of this book is, when the owner of the book is about to die and while laying on the bed (Here it's talking about natural death with aging, because that's how the most of the people died in back old days, no sudden heart attacks) someone else starts reading the book to the owner. The concept behind this is, to make his next life a better one ( next birth in human world or heaven not the hell)

How that happens is the `bhava` in `Pratītyasamutpāda` is caused by the previous `Nidana`s. So if he can have good `Saṅkhāra` (mental fabrication) based on what he hears (from `Pin Potha`) at the last fractions of seconds, it will results to create a good `Bhava`. This is the concept behind this action as I've understood.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. That sounds similar to, `stories in which bhikkhus comfort a dying bhikkhu by asking him to reflect on what he has attained through the practice, which was apparently a common way of encouraging a dying bhikkhu to focus his thoughts on the best object possible` quoted from page 82 of [this](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/thanissaro/bmc1.pdf).

Comment: It's to lift the mind to access-concentration by Caga-nussati, Sila-Nussati, Deva-anussati. And that one does not get fearful and gain so a higher rebirth.

Comment: So modern Sri Lankan will not have much support for good rebirth.

Comment: @SamanaJohann, thing is this is more like a custom or tradition. But according to Dhamma this doesn’t guarantee that the will get a good rebirth. The only guarantee for the good rebirth (not the hell) is being at least a stream entrant. That’s what dhamma says.

Comment: Don't say so, don't say so. The state of mind at death is most relvant for ones rebirth! As Upasaka Lal, since more likely to follow householders advices. As you might no the opposit as well, having hold right view, kept silas, if at the moment of death wrong view, one is destinated to hell. It's pure practice and one should train for the time to come the whole life! Ask those learned scriptual Abhidhamma of what determines the rebirth consciousness. Don't spend time with westerns modern, you loose all your good traditions, Dhamma practice.

Comment: Don't spend time with westerns modern, you loose all your good traditions, Dhamma practice.

Comment: Here, as a sample wheb the Buddha "read" out of "Mahanamas" Merit book: http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/sn/sn55/sn55.021.than_en.html of course to write into one needs to perform fist.

Comment: Nakula's fathers "death story" and the "re-reading from the book" by his wife http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/an/an06/an06.016.than_en.html

Comment: Agreed on your points. What I tried to say is, we should not rely on PinPotha, we should follow the path. With Metta

Comment: Sure, Upasaka, better to remind the good and to desire to repeat if more refined and possible even reach the path.People are advices to relay on their Pin, have kamma, kusala as well as their heritage, relay on it, for better becoming and beyond. See also [advices to Rahula](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/mn/mn.061.than_en.html), as what to make with good deeds after long term reflection:

Comment: "...But if on reflection you know that it did not lead to affliction... it was a skillful mental action with pleasant consequences, pleasant results, then you should stay mentally refreshed & joyful, training day & night in skillful mental qualities." Start as soon as possible to store a "Pin potha".

Comment: Agreed, no argument on that. But when we think widely, why we are loosing these kind of practices? Instead of worrying on the after life, people have started attracting to modern stuff, thinking they can get pleasure out of those, but just because those not make them satisfy they just keep running on these, and forgetting the old customs. Why? That's the nature of the world. It won't behave as we want. So only thing we should do in the present moment is follow the noble path. Coz even if we get a good immediate next birth we can't guarantee the second one, can we?